# How to capture JSON from stdin when parent doesn’t close pipe?

Tags: node.js

I developed a package called [transpile-md-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/transpile-md-to-json) that transpile multiple markdown files to a single JSON file.

Running `transpile-md-to-json --src examples/content --watch` transpiles markdown files to JSON and outputs result to `stdout` as markdown files are created, edited and deleted.

I tried using [get-stdin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-stdin) to capture the JSON and process it some more using another node script.

```
transpile-md-to-json --src src/privacy-guides --blogify --watch | node test.js
```

Problem is `stdin.on('end')` is never fired because the pipe isn’t closed by `transpile-md-to-json` when watch mode is enabled (`--watch`).

See https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-stdin/blob/master/index.js#L23-L25

How can I work around this?

Comment: sounds like you want to file a feature request over on https://github.com/sunknudsen/transpile-md-to-json/issues for that, then? If by design it doesn't signal `end`, request a runtime flag that _does_ make it signal `end`

Comment: What do you mean @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans? I am trying to figure out how to read the `stdout` of `transpile-md-to-json` but, not line by line, rather as a whole, but I don't know how to achieve that (if even possible) because `transpile-md-to-json` doesn’t exit leaving the pipe intact.

Comment: though in this case I'd probably use a file-watch task instead, using [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar), and have _that_ call a `transpile-md-to-json` without the `--watch` flag. Chokidar exists explicitly to watch files and "trigger things when files change", and typically offers you more control. (there's also a `chokidar-cli` if you want to do everything using npm scripts, which is quite reasonable)

Comment: Good gut feeling @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. `transpile-md-to-json` already uses `chokidar` and has a feature to output to file instead of `stdout`. That being said, I am trying to discover the limits of `stdin`.

Comment: Also, feels like watching files might be less efficient that reading pipes for my specific use case... if possible.

Comment: I'd probably still bypass its `--watch` mode, and use your own chokidar task instead. That, or monitor `stdin` manually with a JSON acceptance check (e.g. JSON starts with `{`, so count nested curly brackets and once you see the corresponding closing `}` you know the JSON is done)

Comment: efficiency wise: that sounds unlikely, unless you have thousands of users all editing different md files concurrently, in which case this question would become _far_ more interesting to answer for folks on SO, and you should absolutely describe the real world thing you're working on =)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. So a `JSON acceptance check` is as good as it gets since I can’t capture the `stdin.on('end')` event?

Comment: pretty much. Unless `transpile-md-to-json` emits some kind of custom EOF code that you can be on the lookout for.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Unfortunately, that confirms my gut feeling.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Mike in the comments, there appears to be no built-in way of achieving this as the pipe remains open until the parent exits, therefore `stdin.on('end')` is not fired.

The closest we can get is to use some kind of [EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) indicator and use that to end a "cycle". An indicator we can hook to isn’t always present, but in the context of JSON, we’re good as each JSON payload ends with `}`.

```js
const readline = require("readline")
const fs = require("fs")

process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8")

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
})
var json = ""
rl.on("line", function(line) {
  json += `${line}\n`
  if (line === "}") {
    console.log("done", json)
    fs.writeFileSync("test.json", json)
    json = ""
  }
})
```